# Difference between "I spent a lot of time" and "I have spent a lot of time"

Tags: present-perfect, verb-forms

Can some please explain the difference
1) I spent a lot of time with my friends
2) I have spent a lot of time with my friends

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second implies that there is some particular relevance to the present. The relevance is not specified, but often means that the occasions on which the speaker spends time with their friends is still continuing, or at least regarded as not finished.

The first implies that the occasions on which the speaker spent time with their friends is over. It does not say that they will never spend time with them again, just that they are regarding the series of events as finished.

As usual with the perfect/non-perfect distinction, it is not necessarily expressing an objective difference in the facts, but may be just about how the speaker is choosing to view or refer to the events.

Comment: Can some1 please tell why am I not able to post a queation

Comment: @user3608985 If you read the following link, you will understand. [Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited). Try to visit our Help Center and learn how to ask a good question here.

Comment: Thanks Rathony however I am getting a message we no longer accept queations from this account

Comment: @user3608985 The suspension is only temporary and I believe was triggered automatically. I am not sure how long it will last and you can try it a few days later.